# Identifying largest impact among multiple binary predictor variables on continuous response variable

Tags: multiple-regression, binary-data

I am trying to analyze the effect individual product changes have on the changeover times in a production system to determine which product change incurs the largest "penalty" in a changeover situation.

My data is comprised of 887 observations. Each observation includes 7 binary predictor variables (one for each product feature where 1 = product feature changed and 0 = product feature not changed) and 1 continuous response variable (time spent on performing said changeover). The 7 product features may be combined in a number of ways.

From searching online, it seems that multiple linear regression would be the right way to go. However, I am uncertain whether this is correct and also how multiple linear regression copes with binary predictor variables?

(I am using R, so any suggestions for packages or the like is greatly appreciated!)

Thanks in advance!